# Merge gridview header or merge sub headers of grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know there is possibility to merge gridview columns but my requirement is some thing different from that I would like to have my gridview as follows

[image]

Is it possible to do and also I would like to bind the string values which i will get in a string array.. I would like to create the grid view dynamically and bind the data as per the strings I have is it possible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar situation and ask [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915949/best-way-to-create-dynamic-table-with-left-column-header) few months back. Pivot table help me to solve the issue. check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Pivot.aspx) out.